# Find the absolute minimum and absolute maximum of $|x+2|+7$

Tags: absolute-value

Find the absolute minimum and absolute maximum of $|x+2|+7$.

$|x+2|+7$ was not stated to either be a function or not so what do I do?

Comment: Find the "*absolute minimum and absolute maximum*" of $|x|\,$, then add $+7$ to those.

Comment: You should share your own thoughts and efforts first!

Comment: The question likely means to find the global maxima and minima of $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ where $f(x)=|x+2|+7$.

Answer (score 2):

If we define the function $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ to be
$$f(x) = |x+2| + 7$$
then we can consider the expression
$$|x+2| \geq 0 \\ |x+2| + 7 \geq 7$$
and it will be obvious that this means $f$ has a global minimum of $7$.
There is no upper bound on $f$ so we can conclude that $f$ has no global maximum (as it can take values of $\infty$).